# How to understand shapes of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

For example here is the code snippet

```
kernel = tf.get_variable('conv1_1_Weights', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3, 3, 3, 64], initializer=initer)
```

I do not understand what does the shape of a tensor mean? How do I understand what values kernel has etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kernel` is a tensor with `shape=[3,3,3,64]` that means:

- `3, 3` = kernel width x kernel height
- `3` = kernel depth
- `64` = number of kernel `3 x 3 x 64`

This means that every single kernel is a volume `3x3x3` and you got 64 of this.

The kernel depth is equal to the depth of the input the kernel is convolved with: so you're convolving it with a RGB image, probably.

The output of the convolution of this 3 channel image with 64 kernels `3x3x3` is a volume with depth `64`: one feature map for every convolutional kernel.